# How to call javascript function specified in a child

Tags: javascript, html, web

i tired to call to a function in child (iframe) from specified src.

i tried to work like this:

```html
<iframe id="test" src="www.blabla.com/test.aspx" />
```

```js
document.getElementById('test').contentWindow.helloWorld();
```

But i get an error "acsses denied".

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Both parent and child iframe are in same domain?

Comment: hey  Shubham, no. different domain.

Comment: Then you should have to use [postmessaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to access chlid iframe.

Comment: i read but i don't understand what realy to do. can you explain me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parent Window :

```
var iframeWin = document.getElementById("YourIframeId").contentWindow;
iframeWin.postMessage("You Message String", "*"); /* You can put specific domain in second parameter like www.yourdomain.com. * is for all domains.*/
```

Iframe Window :
    You Should have a listener named message in child Iframe.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.data + "\n" + evt.origin);
});
```